# CFBundleGetVersionNumber returns 0?

Tags: macos, bundle, core-foundation, resourcebundle

An XCode 3.X application running on 10.6.8 has this entry in info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>2035</string>
```

In awakeFromNib() a quick check is made:

```
CFBundleRef br = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
if (br)
{
  uint32_t v32 = CFBundleGetVersionNumber(br);
}
```

The reference is non-zero but the version number is always 0.

Get Info in Finder displays the expected number.

Any ideas why? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [CFBundleGetVersionNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetVersionNumber):

> > **Return Value**
> >
> > A Mac OS `'vers'` resource style version number. If the bundle’s version number is a number, it is interpreted as the unsigned long integer format defined by the `'vers'` resource on **Mac OS 9**. If it is a string, it is automatically converted to the numeric representation, where the major version number is restricted to 2 BCD digits (in other words, it must be in the range 0-99) and the minor and bug fix version numbers are each restricted to a single BCD digit (0-9). See Technical Note TN1132 for more details.
> >
> > **Discussion**
> >
> > This function is only supported for the Mac OS `'vers'` resource style version numbers. Where other version number styles—namely X, or X.Y, or X.Y.Z—are used, you can use `CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey` with the key `kCFBundleVersionKey` to extract the version number as a string from the bundle’s information dictionary.

You're not using the old OS 9-style `'vers'` version resources in a .rsrc file, you're using the modern method of specifying it as a string in an `Info.plist` file.

You could use something like:

```
NSInteger bundleVersion = CFStringGetIntValue(
       CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(br, kCFBundleVersionKey));
```

Comment: Thanks. For any one else interested in this I settled on this:                         'CFStringRef versStr = (CFStringRef) CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),kCFBundleVersionKey);
   const char* vers = CFStringGetCStringPtr(versStr,kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);'

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for `CFBundleGetVersionNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetVersionNumber) - it only supports version numbers of the form `X.Y.Z` where X <= 99, Y <= 9, and Z <= 9. Your version doesn't fall into that range, so you have to use `CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey` with the key `kCFBundleVersionKey` if you want to keep that high number. Alternatively you can change your version format to the Mac OS standard that `CFBundleGetVersionNumber` supports.